# Why are all links are red, in Chrome and Safari?

Tags: css, safari, google-chrome, webkit

Have just started using `Google Chrome`, and noticed in parts of our site, e.g. all the links on the page, are bright red. They should be black with a dotted underline.

Is there some gotcha in `WebKit` rendering that turns all links red regardless of the style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are all of the resources that you're linking to in the  present at the locations where your page is seeking them (verify this by actually checking it). I've also had an issue when checking an app in Safari where I was attempting to pull a file that wasn't there and I had very similar output to yours (red links).

EDIT: Adding Developingchris's find to the answer, since it explains it so well:

> k, found it.
>
> If any of your stylesheets is missing
>   or pathed incorrectly, it throws a
>   404. If your 404 page has inline styles, they get respected via the
>   "alternate sheets" rule in webkit.
>
> Thus, the red links on the "yellow
>   screen of death" are causing my
>   problem in overlap.

Answer (score 2):

k, found it.

If any of your stylesheets is missing or pathed incorrectly, it throws a 404.
If your 404 page has inline styles, they get respected via the "alternate sheets" rule in webkit.

Thus, the red links on the "yellow screen of death" are causing my problem in overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a bug where it [obeys alternate stylesheets](http://jeremyjarratt.com/2008/09/03/google-chrome-obeys-alternate-css/). Do you have an alternate stylesheet that makes links red?

Answer (score 1):

That explains the problem I had with my app--it was a Rails app, which also has 404 pages with red applied to some of the styles. Makes a whole lot more sense now than it did back then. Too bad you can't accept your own answer!

Comment: @icktoofay Do take note of when the question was written.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it wasn't one of the original features. I participated in the beta--this might have been from back then.

Comment: Oh. I thought it was always a feature. I guess I was wrong. Excuse me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a jscript console like firebug to find out where the color comes from

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a `:visited` setting in your stylesheet?

Comment: code is valid. :visited is set, not to red, but its every link, even ones that are backed by js everything works, including the visited stuff, in IE and firefox

Answer (score 0):

Run your CSS file and your HTML file through the w3c validators. I had a similar problem when testing an application in Safari. The problem was in my code.

Comment: External sheet Link not applicable, private beta site on internal ip address.